# jQuery ajax wont load code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

I have an html page, for school and I need to make a menu bar. I want to make it local so I have decided to upload menu.html to media fire

> menu.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse"
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Practice</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"></li>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

my page wont load this file, there is nothing in the output.

> practiceblank.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css"/>
    <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <script>
        var clicks = 0;
        cps = 1;
        function countClicks() {
            clicks += 1;
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="an1">
    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
        jQuery("#div1").load("http://download1473.mediafireuserdownload.com/feen32om7deg/ebw8k296r8caucm/menu.html");
    </script>
<!--The rest is personal-->
```

Comment: I just realised how vague this is. Basically, the 
jQuery("#div1").load("http://download1473.mediafireuserdownload.com/feen32om7deg/ebw8k296r8caucm/menu.html");
is the issue, it just won't appear. If i manually run it in the console, it works

Comment: Yes, I recommend using files locally while coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the include of the library from the script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>    
    $(function(){         
        jQuery("#div1").load("http://download1473.mediafireuserdownload.com/feen32om7deg/ebw8k296r8caucm/menu.html");
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that beforehand, but I guess I just hadn't realised that my code was originally wrong